# Submit a local Apache Flink job with 2 or more task managers

Tags: apache-flink, taskmanager

I am using Apache Flink 1.2.1 version of the product. I'm trying to submit flink job with more than 1 task manager. ( I know by default it is only 1 task manager)
I know that we can start task managers after we submit a job, but can we do that while submitting a flink job?

Where should I specify the number of task managers?

Comment: If you deploy a session cluster, then you have to specify the number of TMs when you start the cluster. If you use the per-job mode (not sure whether 1.2.1 already supports this since it is very old), you can define the number of TMs when you submit the job. Since version 1.5 you don't need to specify the number of TMs when running on Yarn and Mesos. Flink will automatically request as many TMs as required.

Comment: Where do I specify the number of TMs when I deploy a session cluster? In flink.conf file?

Comment: You specify it in the `conf/slaves` file.